# How to automatically update second table with some same information after insert into first table

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I enter a new record in one table, I need to have some of the information from the first table be automatically added to the second table. I unsuccessfully tried triggers to do this.

My primary table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE demographics (
    person_local_id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50)...[other lines]
);
```

I set up the child table like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE pedigree (
      pedigree_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      person_local_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
      person_sex VARCHAR(10),
      father VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 0,
      mother VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 0,
      FOREIGN KEY (person_local_id) REFERENCES demographics (person_local_id) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

My approach was to create a trigger on the demographics primary table such that any time a record was added to it, a corresponding record would be added to the pedigree table consisting of just the person_local_id. I added a foreign key on the pedigree table that referenced the column in the demographics that I need to copy over to the pedigree table in that column.

Then I created a trigger, but it doesn't work. I tried this with and without the word "EXECUTE".

```
CREATE TRIGGER into_pedigree AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON demographics
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE INSERT INTO pedigree (person_local_id) SELECT (NEW.person_local_id) FROM NEW;
```

I keep getting syntax errors but I can't identify the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 2: FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE INSERT INTO pedigree (person_local_id) ...
                             ^
```

I also tried this, adding the name:

```
CREATE TRIGGER into_pedigree ON identify_relatives_database.demographics
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO pedigree (person_local_id) VALUES (INSERTED.person_local_id)
END;
```

But I get the error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: CREATE TRIGGER into_pedigree ON demographics
                                     ^
```

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You need to create trigger function first, and then bind it to trigger.
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/

Comment: @LaKishaDavid . . . Copying data between tables is generally not recommended.  It is better to look up the data when you need it, unless you have a specific performance issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Whenever I add a new record in the demographics table, I need to add a corresponding record in the pedigree table (and corresponding columns in a SNP table).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Customer_INSERT]
           ON [dbo].[demographics]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
           SET NOCOUNT ON;

           DECLARE @CustomerId INT

           SELECT @CustomerId = INSERTED.person_local_id FROM INSERTED

           IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM PEDIGREE WHERE person_local_id = @CustomerId)
           BEGIN
               --- here col is the required column name need to be modified,
               --- since you are inserting person_local_id from base table which is auto generated and not suppose to be change in any condition
                UPDATE PEDIGREE SET COL = INSERTED.COL WHERE person_local_id = @CustomerId 
           END
           ELSE 
           BEGIN 
               INSERT INTO pedigree (person_local_id)
               VALUES(@CustomerId)

           END
    END
```

Although I don't find anything related to your update part. Since you are inserting primary key from base table as foreign key in child table, so for normalization it is not going to changed in any condition. So i don't think you need update part in your trigger Hence your required `trigger` will be:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Customer_INSERT]
           ON [dbo].[demographics]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
           SET NOCOUNT ON; 
            INSERT INTO pedigree (person_local_id)
            SELECT INSERTED.person_local_id FROM INSERTED
    END
```

Comment: You're right; I just need to create a new record in the second table whenever one is created in the first table (INSERT only, not UPDATE). But I can't follow the rest of your first suggestion such as where @CustomerID was coming from. I tried your second suggestion but I still get the error.

Comment: @CustomerId is just a variable to get the value of Id of latest inserted record.

Comment: @LaKishaDavid: What is the error coming in second suggestion part.

Answer (score 0):

> You should try this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER into_pedigree ON demographics
FOR INSERT  
AS  

insert into pedigree (person_local_id)
values(inserted.person_local_id);  

PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'  
GO
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me the error message:

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
`LINE 1: CREATE TRIGGER into_pedigree ON demographics
`